# how to do mouseover and scroll on a table in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, browser-automation, katalon-studio

I am working on Katalon / If solution is in Java selenium also works for me.

I have web table(Angular) with 30+ columns and at a time only 7 columns are visible on screen.
We need to mouseover on table and scroll to see remaining columns as I dont see any element in DOM for scroller to click on left or right arrow
Info:
On windows10 I see scroller but on mac I don't see the scroller, only after 2 finger swipe on mousepad I get scroller and that is also not visible in DOM.

Need help in accessing elements in shadow DOM